# Temporary storage size when installing service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'd like to create a basic (cheap) environment for my service fabric application. However, Service Fabric seems to use the "Temporary Storage" drive of the VMs which is limited in size. The only way I can see to increase the temporary storage drive is to pay for a more performant VM, which I don't really want to do yet.

Is there a way to either, increase the Temporary Storage size, or to tell Service Fabric not to use the Temporary Storage drive, but a different drive?

I am running out of storage in the temp drive, so need to look at other options.

Comment: What are you storing on the temp drive that you need so much space?  Are you aware that the temp drive may not survive reboots/other VM events (host patching, migration, etc...)?

Comment: I'm not storing anything myself. But the service fabric deployment installs my services there, which takes a bit of space, and I assume all the stateful services put their state and replication of state there. Service fabric replicates state across VMs, so is tolerant of VM reboot.

Comment: I see.  I thought you were maybe creating data files directly and storing them on the temporary drive.

Comment: you are limited by storage even when you turn off logging and you use 1 node cluster? something's wrong

Comment: If the storage requirements of the state of my stateful services becomes large, what options do I have? It seems the only thing I can do is increase the VM performance, when all I really want to do is increase the Temporary storage size, is this correct?

Comment: same trap, using the GUI of Azure to define a service fabric cluster, why the Hell is the GUI of azure so limited? I was not even asked to add a data disk. I hate ARM template, but it seems that you should never use the GUI. Falling in one trap after the other with it

Answer (score 1):

The best option for you is creating a custom cluster from an ARM template, setup all requirements like extra disks, disk types, and then deploy a new cluster based on this template.

You can get some templates in [this repository](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-cluster-templates/) and use [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-creation-via-arm) as reference

Answer (score 0):

If you don't configure `MaxDiskQuotaInMB` then Service Fabric diagnostic logs *can* use up 64gigs of temporary storage (d: for Windows or /mnt on Linux).

You can try using VMs with larger temporary storage (64gigs or more) or limit how much storage service fabric allocates for logs by:

1. running this type of Powershell command described [here](https://github.com/Azure/Service-Fabric-Troubleshooting-Guides/blob/master/Cluster/Out%20of%20Diskspace.md)

```
Set-AzureRmServiceFabricSetting -ResourceGroupName clusterResourceGroup -Name clusterName -Section "Diagnostics" -Parameter "MaxDiskQuotaInMB" -Value "25600"
```

2. defining it as part of the arm template like in this [example](https://github.com/DotNetDevOps/DotNetDevOps/blob/f84523892b37ffef0e05118f55a0e13947c49c0e/src/DotNetDevOps.Web/Templates/ServiceFabric/fabric.json#L548)

```json
"parameters": [
  {
    "name": "MaxDiskQuotaInMB",
    "value": 5120
  }
]
```

3. changing it via resources.azure.com by following these [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-config-upgrade-azure#customize-cluster-settings-using-resource-manager-templates) from Microsoft Docs

```json
{
  "name": "Diagnostics",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "MaxDiskQuotaInMB",
      "value": "65536"
    }
  ]
}
```